# Is it ever acceptable to return True when the parameter to Equals is a null reference?

Tags: c#, .net

The docs for `Object.Equals` says that implementors must return false if the parameter is a null reference.

In my class, I'm overriding `Equals` to check for value equality.  I have a member variable which is similar to the `Nullable (T)` structure.  My initial inclination is to return True when I'm passed a null reference and my structure's `HasValue` property is False.

Is it ever acceptable to return True when the parameter to Equals is a null reference?

**EDIT**
For illustration:

```
class ExampleClass {

    SomeValueType? x;

    bool Equals(object other) {
        if (other == null) return false; // <-- returns a different value than x.Equals
        return x.Equals(other); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does null==null? That's a right philosophical can of worms.

Comment: @spender: `Object.Equals` can never be invoked when `this` is `null`, and the literal in code `null==null` is true, so the point is moot.

Comment: Ah. It's only true for convenience. I'm still battling it out in my head.

Comment: The default operator == calls `Object.Equals(Object a,Object b)` which returns `(Object.ReferenceEquals(a,null) ? Object.ReferenceEquals(b,null) : a.Equals(b))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Nullable<T>.Equals(object)` is the following:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (!this.HasValue)
    {
        return (other == null);
    }
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return this.value.Equals(other);
}
```

So the answer to your question is yes in the case of a `struct` (value type) with nullable semantics. If your type is a `class` (reference type), the answer is definitely *no*.

Comment: Well, my class is deferring to my struct's `Equals`.  It just seems unintuitive that it wouldn't defer in the special case of null references

Comment: From the limited information I have now (including your example), your design seems unintuitive. I hold that for a reference type, `Equals` should *always* return `false` when `obj==null`. What exactly are you trying to do here? Why not make `x` a `SomeValueType` instead of `SomeValueType?`?

Comment: It's a wrapper around Nullable(T) which allows inheritors to implement a TryParseValueFromString method.

Comment: @Ken: Follow the well-established .NET framework pattern and place a static `bool TryParse(string, out SomeType)` method in your struct/class. There cannot be confusion about the method signature (name, return value, parameters) because there is no other acceptable way to do this.

Comment: Well, I do follow that pattern except its not static.  It's a member function which will typically call DateTime/Int32/Etc.TryParse().  I'm not sure if you're familiar with `SmartDate` which is a class in CSLA.  It's goal is to be the storage member for a property which a business object exposes as string but is stored in the database as a DateTime.  This is the same concept.  My SmartDate would subclass from the class in question and implement TryParseValue by calling DateTime.TryParse.

Comment: The reason I'm not basing my implementation on SmartDate is because it's implemented as a mutable struct.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing why you couldn't either 1) since it's clearly a date, expose the object as a `DateTimeOffset` (non-nullable) or `DateTimeOffset?` (nullable) or 2) expose a `string` property backed by a `DateTimeOffset`/`DateTimeOffset?` private member and call `ToString` in the getter and `Parse` in the setter when the value is not `null`.

Comment: I get it now.  Thanks for your help.  I won't store my struct inside my "Smart" classes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not. The equals method cannot return true when two objects are null.

Why?

Well when you define

```
AnObject obj;
```

obj is a reference to an object (I am talking for Java but this must be a OO concept)

Object.Equals method takes a parameter which must be an object however null is not an object.

so null.Equals(null) is not an acceptable approach for OO.

Edit:

That's why == operator differs from obj.Equals method. null == null returns true without any headache.

Edit2: It seems that .Net has an inconsistency about Equals method which may be subject to another topic.

```
int? a = null;
a.Equals(null); // returns true without any problem.
```

but:

`Nullable<T>.Equals` method is defined like this:

```
Nullable<T>.Equals(object obj):bool
```

> Indicates whether the current
>   Nullable value is equal to a
>   specified **object**

Since null is not an object, either the documentation or the implementation is not correct.

Comment: More specifically, this is the difference between the static method `Object.Equals(Object,Object)` and the virtual member method `Object.Equals(Object)`. Your answer doesn't account for the fact that according to the standard (ECMA-335) the special value type `Nullable<T>` boxes to `null` whenever `HasValue` is false.

Comment: @jcasso: The standard, ECMA-335, specifically gives special semantics to the value type `System.Nullable<T>`, which boxes to the object reference `null` whenever `HasValue` is `false`. The only other option would be to make `Nullable<T>` a reference type that could actually be set to a `null` reference, but that would have a significant (negative) impact on performance because it would effectively be the same as boxing/unboxing the underlying type.

Comment: @280Z28 It seems that Nullable<T>.equals(object) method does a different job here. It overrides System.Object.Equals method. Does not throw exception if the HasValue property is false... As I mentioned above I was talking for Java but what we talk here is not about just a language, it is about Object Oriented Programming.

And for me I still insist that this is a very bad approach. Equals mehtod must compare to objects, not the references of objects.

Comment: And also "an object may or may not be equal to an object if it does not have a value" algorithm? Congratulations to the inventor.